# ASP.Net + IIS 7 + charset 1251

Tags: asp.net

Проблема следующего характера.
1.Имеется IIS 7 , на нем разворачивается сайт ASP. Все страницы, генерируемые сайтом имеют кодировку UTF-8 и там весь текст с кириллицей отражается корректно. Потребовалось(для сопряжения со сторонним сервисом) создать страницу без HTTP тегов(!!!!), где выводится только текст с разделителями в формате КЛЮЧ=ЗНАЧЕНИЕ (ключ - всегда латиница, значение может быть и кириллицей). 2.Сторонний сервис работает с кириллицей, но только в кодировке win-1251. Соответственно выводимый через эту страницу текст в кириллице некорректно интерпретируется на стороннем сервисе. При этом если создать обычную статическую страницу с подобным содержанием в виде test.html , то IIS автоматически выдает для нее кодовую страницу 1251 и текст на стороннем сервисе отражается корректно.Также замечено , что для динамической страницы сервер автоматически выбирает utf-8 (видно в свойстве text/html; charset=utf-8), а для тестовой test.html сервер автоматом выбирает win-1251 (в свойстве при этом имеется только text/html и никакого указания на кодировку)
3. Пробовал добавлять в настройках ISS в http-заголовках строку (name: Content-Type ; text/html; charset=windows-1251), после чего в динамических страницах стало появляться поле  text/html; charset=utf-8,text/html; charset=windows-1251 (как видно 2 charset подставляются), но результата нет.
4.Позже выяснил, что все-таки проблема в том, что ASP сам текст выводит в среду разработки в utf-8. Для решения проблемы пробовал перекодировать некоторые строки из utf-8 в win-1251 через методы Encoding.Convert (через байтовые последовательности). В итоге в браузер выводится обработанный текст через коды символов (например, С) но сторонний сервис все-равно не воспринимает это.

Нужна консультация, куда смотреть и что делать.
(PS . Нормальные метки для темы сайт не дает ставить - говорит карма у меня низкая (ниже 300)

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете WebForms, то кодировка вывода указывается в директиве Page:

```
<%@Page CodePage="windows-1251" %>
```

Обратите внимание, что эта кодировка никак не связана с кодировкой ваших исходников.

В случае использование ASP.NET MVC кодировку вы можете указать в контроллере:

```
Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251);
```

Для ASP.NET Core это делается чуть сложнее:

```
var mediaType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain");
mediaType.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251);
Response.ContentType = mediaType.ToString();
```

Comment: Спасибо за консультацию. Используется MVC. Сделал в соответствие с вашей рекомендацией , теперь весь  текст (кириллицу) на динамических выводит в десятичном коде (в браузере отражается корректно, но в коде html - это символы , начинающиеся на &#  ) - это не тот результат. Нужно именно чтобы было идентично исходнику

Comment: Вот пример :  В коде = &#x41F;&#x420;&#x41E;&#x412;&#x415;&#x420;&#x41A;&#x410;   В браузере = ПРОВЕРКА

Comment: Дополню информацию - указанные в предыдущем сообщении коды, как я понял, это все-таки коды для UTF-8. И отражаются они(кириллистические буквы) в браузере корректно, как я понял, потому то браузер однозначно определяет эти коды как utf-8 по каким-то внутренним алгоритмам, и, даже принудительная смена кодировки генерируемой страницы на это никак не влияет.Даже если в этой ситуации переключать кодировку на отражаемой странице одинаково корректно будет отражаться.Получается , что где-то в ASP надо менять механизм формирования текста, чтобы вместо кодов выдавались реальные кириллистические символы.